# django - similar management commands for different django apps

Tags: python, django

I am using *django* now, I have created a django-project with three django-apps in it.
Each app can be used in isolation, without the others, but all three apps are working together somehow.
For each app I have custom commands for unit-, integration- and end-to-end-tests.

```
project/
+---- app1/
|       +- management/commands/
|            +- unittest.py
|            |
|            +- integrationtest.py
|            |
|            +- etoetest.py
+---- app2/
|       +- management/commands/
|            +- unittest.py
|            |
|            +- integrationtest.py
|            |
|            +- etoetest.py
+---- app3/
|       +- management/commands/
|            +- unittest.py
|            |
|            +- integrationtest.py
|            |
|            +- etoetest.py
```

What I want to know, is there a way to run manage.py inside the project and give it some kind of argument to specify the app for which a command has to be executed?
I want to do something like this:
`./manage.py unittest app1 --arg0 ...`
If there is a way, where in the project should the solution live?

I tried implementing djangos AppCommand or playing with different settings.py to execute the desired commands. But each of the two solutions did not feel right and did not really integrate well into the overall architecture of the project.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't. Management commands are intended to be executed from a command line.

I would create app1_unittest, app2_unittest, app3_unittest. Ditto the others.

To run all, you  would write a script. You might use bash, or you might use python subprocess.run. Bash might  be as simple as

```
set -x
./manage.py app1_unittest $*
./manage.py app1_unittest $*
./manage.py app1_unittest $*
```

python subprocess.run would let you write it as a management command

```
./manage.py all_unittests
```

Comment: Wait, write bash to call Python code and call bash from Python? Really? `django.core.management.call_command`

Comment: @STerliakov not what I meant! Just if you often want to run a set of management commands, package that up as a bash script and use that from your command line to drive Django. For tighter integration as I said, you could use python subprocess.run to execute one management (sub)command from inside another. Although, no actual reason subprocess couldn't invoke a bash script.

Comment: I understand your idea, thank you. But this would be a way to work around Django right?

Comment: @Fylyp Yes, I guess so. I  did briefly  look at the source of django.core.management.base to see if there was an obvious and simple way to do it by subclassing BaseCommand but it's rather complex in there. Simple beats elegant in my book, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will go with this approach:

```
project/
+---- shared/
|       +- shared/
|            +- unittest.py 
|            |
|            +- integrationtest.py 
|            |
|            +- etoetest.py 
|
+---- app1/
|       +- management/commands/
|            +- unittest.py
|            |
|            +- integrationtest.py
|            |
|            +- etoetest.py
+---- app2/
|       +- management/commands/
|            +- unittest.py
|            |
|            +- integrationtest.py
|            |
|            +- etoetest.py
+---- app3/
|       +- management/commands/
|            +- unittest.py
|            |
|            +- integrationtest.py
|            |
|            +- etoetest.py
|
+---- project/
        +- settings/
             +- app1/
             |    +- settings.py
             |
             +- app1/
             |    +- settings.py
             |
             +- app1/
                  +- settings.py
```

I have created a shared directory which contains the implementation of the command. The command is parametrizable by passing specific arguments to it in its constructor, like setting path. Each app specific command will inherit from the shared command and set its parameters accordingly.
To call app1 I need to call

```
./manage.py unittest --settings project.settings.app1.settings
```

and to call app2 I need to call

```
./manage.py unittest --settings project.settings.app2.settings
```

For now, this approach fits best to my project architecture.